# I don't understand why in ssh public/private key authentication, public key goes on server

Tags: authentication, ssh, rsa

In most Unix systems we have authentication scheme with public/private key.

Private key allows owner to decrypt, public key allows owner to encrypt something private key owner can decrypt.

Let's say user wants to login onto a server using this auth scheme.

In Unix systems, public key is put on the server, private key is used to generate a signature for the server to verify.

However this doesn't make sense to me from a "mechanical" perspective, if public key is used to encrypt, how is it used to verify the signature generated by a private key? Because it only encrypts right?

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9896/how-does-rsa-signature-verification-work

Comment: This is fundamental to [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography#Description)

Answer (score 2):

Encryption is just one use case for a key pair. The public key is used to encrypt so that you can ensure that only a holder of the private key can decrypt.

For signatures, the private key is use to "encrypt", or sign, so that you can be certain of the source of the message. The remote host then uses the public key to "decrypt", or verify, the signature.